# Enabling debug symbols in linux kernel

Tags: linux, debugging, compilation

I am trying to compile the linux kernel here with changes in .config file as follows:

```
# CONFIG_DEBUG_RODATA is not set
CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y
CONFIG_KGDB=y
CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y
CONFIG_KGDB_KDB=y
CONFIG_KDB_KEYBOARD=y
```

as mentioned [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/CompileKDB.html). However when I check the vmlinux file for debug symbols, I am unable to see any debug symbols when I load vmlinux with gdb.

One of the many posts that I have come across says to enable

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
```

But this option does not seem to be available in default .config file. (I am using Ubuntu 15.04 Linux version 3.19.0 that I downloaded using

```
apt-get source
```

And did the following after downloading the source:

```
make
make modules
make modules_install
make install
```

Please let me know what additional changes are required to create a debug kernel build, and a also a debug module.

Comment: Have you tried to ask this on askubuntu ?

Comment: No, I will add the question to askubuntu. thank you. But I think there is some generic error I am doing which I think maybe all linux developers would know.

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution?